# VM software that can boot to Windows partition created by Boot Camp

Tags: software-recommendation, bootcamp, virtualization

Does anybody know if any VM software can boot Windows from the other partitions on the internal HDD?

Here is what mine looks like:

- HDD

  - OS X partition
  - Windows Boot Camp partition

**Objective**: Running OS X, but booting into windows through a VM environment from the HD installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/) and [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/en/products/desktop/) support running VMs directly from Bootcamp partitions. They also offer migration from a partition to a VM image if you ever want to go that route.

It appears that it's also possible with [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org), but not a supported feature. I [found this blog post](http://phaq.phunsites.net/2011/03/05/sharing-windows-7-between-boot-camp-and-virtualbox/) detailing how to configure it (the post also lists several other sources that may be helpful).

#### Relevant support articles:

- [Launching your Boot Camp partition in VMware Fusion](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014618)
- [Parallels: Using Boot Camp Partition in Virtual Machine](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v6/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/23112.htm)

Comment: +1 But, I would never recommend VirtualBox for something like this.  It's more trouble than its worth for just _regular_ use, let alone this.